# How to add restrictions like sizelimit and type while uploading images and pdf files in dam in AEM?

Tags: adobe, aem

I want to add restrictions on uploading assets like images and pdf like size limit and type in the dam in aem.how to add this thing in aem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be making some customizations to the OOTB AEM functionality. 
Check the approach mentioned below for size limit.

- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2322443

For the type restriction, you would have to make the config changes mentioned below.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/configuring-asset-upload-restrictions.html

Comment: thanks.but I want add restrictions for image type and size, same time with pdfs also so how can I do this?